How to completely disable VS Code merge editor?
When I run git cherry-pick, VS Code automatically starts the merge editor.
For some unknown reason, it alters the content of the conflict files and immediately autosaves those changes to the disk, so they remain when I resolve the conflict through the terminal.
Moreover, that thing just doesn't work correctly, and when it does, it just throws an error without a description and refuses to continue!
How can I get rid of that thing?
I disabled every checkbox in settings related to merging, expecting to turn off that thing, but nothing changed.
I tried to google the solution but found only recommendations to disable those checkboxes.
Then I asked ChatGPT. It told me to add a few lines in settings.json, but it wasn't helpful either. Here's what ChatGPT suggested:
{
    "git.mergeEditor": false,
    "git.openDiffOnClick": false,
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.merge": "default"
    },
    "git.enableSmartCommit": false
}



If you want to completely disable the VS Code Merge Editor, you should not only disable the git.mergeEditor setting, but also disable the built-in Merge Conflict extension.

Doing so, the editor will be presented just like regular Git merge conflicts, in text mode, with no Code Actions on top of the conflicts.

